# Magento 2 Core Bug Found Discount Shows wrong On Catelog Page, But Discount price calculate fine

Tags: magento2

[image]I can see that there are issue in magento2 in my project, i applied 20% discount on all items, but its shown different disscount % on Product Detail Page, I am not able to figure out , what can i do, plz let me know,
Here you can see Discount amount showing 38% instead of 20%, but price calculation is fine.

Comment: http://qaabheri.aimbeyond.com/

Comment: Please have look

Comment: Which type of product is this one? and how you set the discount for this one?